# Laravel 4 - Hide variables from URL.

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following Route:

```
 Route::resource('projects.deliveries.tasks', 'TaskController');
```

And of course if I want to create a task, my URL looks like this:

```
 http:://test.dev/projects/1/deliveries/3/tasks/create
```

For Project Number 1 and delivery number 3.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/InhM6.jpg

But I don't want the number to show up in the URL, because tasks should be creatable, without authentication or login.

Is there a way to hide these numbers, so that I get a clean URL like this:

```
http:://test.dev/projects/delivereis/tasks/create
```

And Laravel understands from my logic, that it is Project 1 and devivery 3 for which a task is to be created?

Comment: For that I think you should create a custom resource.

Comment: How can it know you mean project 1 and delivery 3? Do you have (and will you always have) only one project and only one delivery?

Comment: I'm assuming there will be a form where these are chosen, in which case the `Input` class would be utilized to retrieve these variables.  Why would the numbers in the URI keep a user from editing these if not logged in?  This seems more like a filter problem.

Comment: In a resource, the create method shouldn't be explicitly called, this should be done by the RESTful state, meaning that when a RESTful POST is done to `http:://test.dev/projects/1/deliveries/3/tasks/` the create method is called by the resource controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you should probably specify your routes manually. Using `Route::resource()` is great if you're absolutely going to use the resource as intended (with verbose routes) but it doesn't provide you with much flexibility. In fact for most projects it's actually recommended that you do define all your routes manually to give you the most control (and it's also great self-documentation in your `routes.php` file).

```
Route::get('projects/deliveries/tasks/create', ['as' => 'projects.deliveries.tasks.create', 'uses' => 'TasksController@create']);
Route::post('projects/deliveries/tasks', ['as' => 'projects.deliveries.tasks.store', 'uses' => 'TasksController@store']);
```